# Default search options clear out with every Chrome restart

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome

I'm having a problem with Chrome on a Ubuntu netbook edition install. Every time I restart Chrome the "Default search" option list has cleared. I can do 'Manage' and add google back in, but if I stop and start Chrome, the list is empty again.

I'm running the stable version of Chrome and this has been like this for months now.

Anyone had a similar issue or know what could possibly cause this?

I've tried to reinstall chrome, run the unstable version and various other things I hoped would make the problem go away. None of that worked. I'd prefer a solution that actually finds the underlying issue and fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting ~/.config/google-chrome/Default starting chrome after that creates a new profile, meaning all bookmarks history and everything is gone. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling or clearing profile just seems to work until the next restart.
Apparently the issue is known and people work on it:
 - http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=10913

Answer (score 0):

May be its a simple setting that is giving you problems. 
Try: Settings -> Options -> {Then set your home page} 
or
 if that doesn't work simply reinstall. I think that should do it :)